# Why using first fundamental form on regular surfaces and riemannian metric on smooth manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

In the study of regular surfaces, it's common to call a notion intrinsic to a regular surface $S$ if it can be expressed only with the knowledge of its the first fundamental form $\textbf{I}$. In this definition, it's equivalent to replace the first fundamental form with the induced scalar product from $\mathbb{R}^3$ on all tangent spaces of the surface. Indeed, this is because we have
$$\langle v,w\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\big(\textbf{I}(v+w) - \textbf{I}(v) - \textbf{I}(w) \big)$$ for all $v,w \in T_p S$ and for all $p \in S$.

On the study of Riemannian manifolds which generalize the regular surface case, the role of the first fundamental form in the definition of *intrinsic* is replaced with the riemannian metric.

My question is the following : Why do we not use the first fundamental form on both cases ? Alternatively, why do we not use the riemannian metric on both cases ? Is it only a pedagogical choice from the author ?

Thank you.

Comment: I agree that transitioning from "embedded differential geometry" (like most introductory courses on surfaces) to "abstract differential geometry" begs this kinds of questions.

One particular thing that bothers me is that I got used to calculating scalar curvature through the 2nd fundamental form pretty quick. That approach is futile in "abstract intrinsic Riemannian manifolds".

Comment: Note that even though you can embed any finite-dimensional real manifold inside some $\mathbb{R}^N$, I suspect that you cannot do whatever you like so as to make the intrinsic metric you started from agree with the ambient one endowed by the particular embedding you chose.

Comment: I once heard a professor say "first fundamental norm is the name we use when teaching this to children". They're the same thing: a field of inner products on the tangent spaces of whatever manifold you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first fundamental form is identically the same as a Riemannian metric. Although your text seems to treat $\mathbf I$ as a quadratic form — taking an input of a *single* tangent vector, most of us define it as a *bilinear* form — that is, taking a pair of tangent vectors $v,w$ as input. We would write $\mathbf I(v,v)$ where you're writing $\mathbf I(v)$. At any rate, for a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$, the induced Riemannian metric comes about just as you understand for surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$.